# Spring Boot with Apache Cassandra and liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, nosql, database-migration, liquibase

I want to integrate Spring Boot (2.4.13) with Apache Cassandra and liquibase. My goal very simple, to insert changestes during application startup. I found a lot of examples/tutorials  but not for my setup. My problem is that liquibase is not working. There is nothing in logs and nothing changed in DB.

Does someone know what could be wrong with my config or what I did wrong?

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Cassandra</name>
    <description>Cassandra</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properties

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=test
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.password=cassandra
spring.data.cassandra.username=cassandra
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

My changelog-master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.10.xsd">

    <changeSet id="202010211812" author="test">
        <createTable tableName="testtt">
            <column name="tableone" type="BOOLEAN"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

My project structure

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the tutorial for using Liquibase with Cassandra? https://docs.liquibase.com/start/install/tutorials/cassandra.html

Comment: I saw that, but it didn't help.

Comment: You are on an older version of the cassandra extension. The newest version is 4.18.0 which works for sure with liquibase 4.18.0. If you upgrade liquibase-cassandra and explicitly set liquibase-core to 4.18.0 as well, does that help?

Comment: I don't think it is a version problem. I had a problem to integrate all this stuff togheter and I think I found why I couldn't do that : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29991